# HTML5 Canvas Viewport for Web Application

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to get my head around this for a couple of days now and can't work it out from similar questions.

There are 2 canvases, a scaled viewport that shows a portion of a larger background, and a zoomed-out camera map. When the second canvas is clicked, the viewport should move to that area of the background.

```js
var onClick,
onLoad = function () {
    var canvas,
        viewport,
        context,
        canvasWidth,
        canvasHeight,
        viewportContext,
        background = {},
        camera,
        scale = 4;

    function init() {
        background.image = new Image();
        background.image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Coronation_of_Ahmad_Shah_Durrani_in_1747_by_Breshna.jpg";
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        viewport = document.getElementById("viewport");
        viewportContext = viewport.getContext("2d");
        camera = {
            x: canvas.width/2,
            y: canvas.height/2,
            width: canvas.width/scale,
            height: canvas.height/scale
        };
        background.width = canvas.width * scale;
        background.height = canvas.height * scale;
       
    };
 
   // Translate viewport's context to camera pos
    function moveContext() {
        viewportContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // Reset context
        viewportContext.translate(camera.x*scale, camera.y*scale);
    };
 
   // Update camera's position
    function moveCamera(vector) {
        camera.x = vector.x;
        camera.y = vector.y;
        moveContext();
    };

    function draw() {
        context.drawImage(background.image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      // Draw camera guide
        context.strokeStyle = 'red';
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(camera.x - camera.width / 2, camera.y - camera.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(camera.x + camera.width / 2, camera.y - camera.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(camera.x + camera.width / 2, camera.y + camera.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(camera.x - camera.width / 2, camera.y + camera.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(camera.x - camera.width / 2, camera.y - camera.height / 2);
        context.stroke();
  
       // Draw viewport background
        viewportContext.clearRect(0, 0, viewport.width, viewport.height);
        viewportContext.drawImage(background.image, -background.width/2, -background.height/2, background.width, background.height);
    };

    function update() {
    };

    function gameLoop() {
        update();
        draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    };


    onClick = function (event) {
        var x = event.offsetX,
            y = event.offsetY;

        //alert("x: " + x + "\ny: " + y);
        moveCamera({ x: x, y: y });
    };


    init();
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

    
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", onLoad, false);
    window.addEventListener("click", function () { onClick(event) }, false);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display:block;
  margin:15px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="viewport" width="400" height="240">HTML5 Canvas not supported!</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="240"></canvas>
```

Currently I'm getting the coordinates of a mouse click, setting the camera to that position, resetting the transformation matrix of the viewport and then translating the viewport's context to the camera position.

Obviously, there is a fundamental part of the theory that I'm missing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your transformations are wrong, they are reversed and have a half-width offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your transformations, like I said in the comment. Try this:

```
    function moveContext() {
        viewportContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // Reset context
        viewportContext.translate(
            (viewport.width/2-camera.x+camera.width/2)*scale,
            (viewport.height/2-camera.y+camera.height/2)*scale
        );
    };
```

---

The whole thing:

```js
var onClick,
onLoad = function () {
    var canvas,
        viewport,
        context,
        canvasWidth,
        canvasHeight,
        viewportContext,
        background = {},
        camera,
        scale = 4;

    function init() {
        background.image = new Image();
        background.image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Coronation_of_Ahmad_Shah_Durrani_in_1747_by_Breshna.jpg";
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        viewport = document.getElementById("viewport");
        viewportContext = viewport.getContext("2d");
        camera = {
            x: canvas.width/2,
            y: canvas.height/2,
            width: canvas.width/scale,
            height: canvas.height/scale
        };
        background.width = canvas.width * scale;
        background.height = canvas.height * scale;
       
    };
 
   // Translate viewport's context to camera pos
    function moveContext() {
        viewportContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // Reset context
        viewportContext.translate(
            (viewport.width/2-camera.x+camera.width/2)*scale,
            (viewport.height/2-camera.y+camera.height/2)*scale
        );
    };
 
   // Update camera's position
    function moveCamera(vector) {
        camera.x = vector.x;
        camera.y = vector.y;
        moveContext();
    };

    function draw() {
        context.drawImage(background.image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      // Draw camera guide
        context.strokeStyle = 'red';
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(camera.x - camera.width / 2, camera.y - camera.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(camera.x + camera.width / 2, camera.y - camera.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(camera.x + camera.width / 2, camera.y + camera.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(camera.x - camera.width / 2, camera.y + camera.height / 2);
        context.lineTo(camera.x - camera.width / 2, camera.y - camera.height / 2);
        context.stroke();
  
       // Draw viewport background
        viewportContext.clearRect(0, 0, viewport.width, viewport.height);
        viewportContext.drawImage(background.image, -background.width/2, -background.height/2, background.width, background.height);
    };

    function update() {
    };

    function gameLoop() {
        update();
        draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    };


    onClick = function (event) {
        var x = event.offsetX,
            y = event.offsetY;

        //alert("x: " + x + "\ny: " + y);
        moveCamera({ x: x, y: y });
    };


    init();
    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

    
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", onLoad, false);
    window.addEventListener("click", function () { onClick(event) }, false);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display:block;
  margin:15px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="viewport" width="400" height="240">HTML5 Canvas not supported!</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="240"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you expand on the reasoning behind the new transformations? Why have you subtracted the camera position from the centre of the viewport?

Comment: It was a couple of trial and error attempts. The centre of the viewport was added because you're already using halves to render the viewport at the centre, thus that negative offset. The camera width/height offset is to compensate for the red box (Camera) size.

Comment: Usually, when you're doing something like this, it's the best to check what happens in marginal cases, so all four corners, that's what I started from.